# HTTP 404 when linking dojo/dojo.js script src in Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring, model-view-controller, dojo, http-status-code-404

Ok, so I've been stuck trying to setup a Spring MVC project integrated with DOJO for some time now.  Finally decided it was time to make an account here and ask the question.  I have everything loading except for my dojo.js file that I am referencing from my  tag.  I'll provide my project hierarchy and what I'm seeing:

My @RequestMapping method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rbd", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }
```

..When I browse to `http://localhost:8080/myproject/rbd` the application is successfully loading the home.jsp file, which is shown below:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />

<link rel="icon" href="../sba-icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../sba-icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />

<script src="<spring:url value='/scripts/dojo/dojo.js'/>" data-dojo-config:"locale:'en', async:true, parseOnLoad:false"></script>
```

..My JBOSS deployments folder follows the hierarchy myproject/scripts/dojo/dojo.js.  My home.jsp is in myproject/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp.  Is the location of the src tag relative to the location of the home.jsp? I'm so lost because I keep getting 404 errors.. yet I obviously know that dojo.js is on the server.  I've tried every path that makes sense to me, I am a Spring/MVC beginner, so don't bash please!

Thanks for the help! :)

EDIT:  Here is my init of my DispatcherServlet within my web.xml  ...

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>rbd</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/rbd/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rbd</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

..And here is my servlet-context.xml located in the path shown above..

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: What is your `DispatcherServlet` mapped to?

Comment: sorry Sotirios, I'm new to Spring so I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. I edited my original post with my DispatcherServlet information at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Since your have a resource handler mapped to `/resources`, put your `scripts` in `/resources` and access it accordingly.

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean. i linked my built scripts folder inside my resources folder, still getting 404

Comment: edit:: so i changed my mapping to <resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" /> and then I no longer get the 404! Still more issues i need to resolve, but i guess that's normal with a first time project setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have no mapping to your `/scripts` directory. When using Spring MVC, each request is being mapped to something. You have mapped the following:

- **/rbd**: In your controller
- **/resources**: In your `servlet-context.xml` (as a resource)

As you can see there's no kind of mapping for the `/scripts` directory, so in order to make it work you should either move it to the resources-folder (and adjust the links) or provide some additional mapping, by adding the following to your configuration:

```xml
 <resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />
```

Without it  Spring simply doesn't know where it should refer to when you're trying to access Dojo.

Answer (score 0):

DispatcherServlet intercepts the js file
you should set `<servlet-mapping>` like:

```
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rbd</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

meanwhile change your controller mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rbd.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```